# query data from one model, filter from another

Tags: python, django

I would like to display values from one table, but filter these values based on a value from another table.

for example: I want to display values from data/models.py that are filtered by the customer_tag in the CustomUser table (accounts/models.py).
These are related tables, but I can't figure out the right syntax to filter this view. 
Any ideas? Or is this not possible with my current schema..

**data/views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, DeleteView, CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Data
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Data
from accounts.models import CustomUser
from .serializers import DataSerializer
from .permissions import IsAuthorOrReadOnly

class DataListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    queryset = Data.objects.all()
    context = {
        "object_list": queryset
    }
    template_name = 'data_list.html'
    login_url = 'login'
```

**accounts/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    customer_Tag = models.CharField(max_length=50,)
    isAdmin = models.BooleanField(default = False,)
    notifications = models.BooleanField(default = True,)
    deviceSerial= models.CharField(max_length=50,)
    machineName= models.CharField(max_length=50,default="ESP1",)
    machineDescription = models.CharField(max_length=200,)

class Customer(models.Model):
    customerTag= models.CharField(max_length=50,) 
    customerName = models.CharField(max_length=50,)
    mainContact = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='',)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='',)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='',)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=100,default='',)
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customerName
```

**data/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class Data(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    tempData= models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,)
    humidData= models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,)


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.author)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Fields of related models are queried using double underscores `__` in a filter.

In your case you need to override `get_queryset` method of your `DataListView` class to return a filtered queryset:

```
class DataListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
...
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.queryset.filter(author__customerTag=self.request.user.customerTag)
```

Comment: Thanks this pretty much did it!
I just changed the last line to: 
return Data.objects.filter(author__customer_Tag=self.request.user.customer_Tag)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the key__field argument of the filter query if I understood you correctly. So in your case it would be something like,

```
Data.objects.filter(author__customer_tag='tag-you-are-looking-for')   # double underscores after author
```

Hope this answers your question!